# Google Project asks me to authorize my Google scripts again every week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, permissions

I have asked Google One support, and they gave me bad and/or automatic non-answers.

I have a Google One account (not Google Business) where I use Gmail and Docs to run a small Tour Operator. I wrote some Google Apps (javascript functions) in my main Google Spreadsheet to automatize my tasks and needs.

For example, one function is NewBooking.gs that will trigger every time there is a change in the Spreadsheet. It will then try to access the Spreadsheet and later access my Gmail. If the permissions are up to date, it runs perfectly. The problem is that the permissions get outdated like every week. If the NewBooking is being triggered by me manually running it from the Google Apps Editor, Google asks me for a manual authorization (click over Allow the Project to access Gmail and Google Docs).

The real problem is that I need the NewBooking function to be triggered by a DoPost (serverbased), when I will not know nor be asked to allow the permissions, because it is automatic and it is not being done in the client side.

Besides having Google Apps I also have other python functions accessing my Google Docs and Google Email that I run manually through my terminal sometimes, and I had to create an exception to capture the lack of permission, to be able to catch the link so I can paste it in my browser to click on the Allow button, so the token file is refreshed in my machine and the code resumes.

If I look in my Google Cloud Console, Gmail, GDocs are enabled, and the keys are the correct ones that I use in the Apps and in the terminal.

This is an example of error I get from a triggered Apps function, if the permission is outdated (I need to manually run it later to allw it):

Oct 6, 2023, 8:25:44 AM Error   Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/) at BookingsFromEmail(BookingsFromEmail:47:26)

So, my dear collective brain: anyone knows if I can set the permission to not get outdated, so I don't need to constantly renew it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a consumer grade account (email ends in gmail dot com)? Is your script associated with a standard GCP project? If yes to those questions, then your script's tokens (both refresh and access) are revoked after 7 days. You'll need to have your script verified. But since you're using restricted Gmail scopes it will also have to undergo a security assessment...and you might incur expensive charges. If you can afford it sign up for a business-grade account, they go for US$6.00 per user per month at the lowest tier. Business-grade accounts don't require verification for private scripts.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Any source for this 7 daysx Standard GCP?

Comment: I am using a consumer grade account @gmail.com. It is associated to a standard GCP project. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TheMaster I can confirm it's every 7 days by experience.